# Azure / New portal / Team services / Azure web app deploy / Co-admin only?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a question regarding Visual Studio Team services / Azure Web App deploy

in order to get my app be published using the Azure Web app deployment in release process, I had to grant access as co-administrator on my azure subscription using the old management manage.windowsazure.com

Is there any way to do the same thing using the new portal.azure.com ?

As we work as a big team, I would like to be very restrictive on users right and I do not want everybody to be co-admin. Is there any other way to grant publishing privileges on specific account (we use an Azure AD connected to VSTS) without giving Azure co admin privileges ?

Answer (score 2):

@Thierry,

new new portal "https://portal.azure.com", you can config access with role base access management.where you can more granular permission (read/contributor/owner) to a user for a specific resources (service/resource group/subscriptions etc ...)

See more details from this articile https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-configure/

hope this will help!